# Expected End of Statement error in vbs file

Tags: firefox, vbscript, proxy, settings

I'm automating the task of disabling the Proxy on Mozilla firefox (it currently defaults to 'Automatic proxy config url' and I manually set it to 'No Proxy').

After some research, I realised the settings can be changed by creating a user.js file (which overrides the firefox settings stored in pref.js) that contains this:

```
user_pref("network.proxy.type", 0);
```

Below is the vbs syntax i'm having issues with:

```
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

outFile="%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\3b59qrw5.default\user.js"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
objFile.Write "user_pref("network.proxy.type", 0);" & vbCrLf
objFile.Close
```

When executing the vbs file, I get this error

Line 5
Char 27
Expected end of statement
800A0401

Any help would be great,
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

VBScript strings are delimited by double quotes. If you want to use double quotes inside strings in VBScript, you must either escape them by using double double quotes:

```
objFile.Write "user_pref(""network.proxy.type"", 0);" & vbCrLf
```

or insert literal double quotes (ASCII character 34) by concatenation:

```
objFile.Write "user_pref(" & Chr(34) & "network.proxy.type" & Chr(34) _
  & ", 0);" & vbCrLf
```