# VBS eqivalent of a working vba code

Tags: vba, vbscript

I'm new to VB scripting though I have a little familiarity in VBA.

The VBA code which I have written is working fine but when I tried to convert it into VBS file it throws Run time error "Expected End of Statement- 800A0401" in the following line

```
wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, f2) = get_split_strings(0) & "pass %"
```

get_split_strings(0) is an array and what I want to do is append the string "pass %" to it.What I am actually doing is opening a HTML file as a excel file for processing and saving it back as a HTML file.

```
Set wb1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = wb1.Workbooks.Open("file:///Pathname/filename.html")

If (f1 + 1) = lastrow And (f2) < lastcolumn Then
wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(f1 + 1, f2) = Round((Per_Sum / (lastrow - 2)), 0)
wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, f2) = get_split_strings(0) & "pass %" **Getting Error here**
f2 = f2 + 3
f1 = 1
Per_Sum = 0
End If
```

Added as per comment

```
        get_split_strings(0) = Split(wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, f2), "_", -1, vbBinaryCompare)
```

get_split_strings(0) contains the header contents. Basically a string data. In the above line the value of f2 is incremented to parse through the columns to find the header contents.

It worked with a small work around.Removed the usage of get_split_string(0).

```
wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,f2)= wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,f2) & " pass %"
```

Comment: Have you created `excel.application` objectin your VBS script?

Comment: Yes I have did that. I have edited the question for your reference. Thanks.

Comment: We cannot reproduce the issue with the information you gave. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is the value of `get_split_strings(0)`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Edited the question as per your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Split()` produces an array, which you then assign to `get_split_strings(0)` (the first element of the array `get_split_strings`). Why are you doing that, BTW? What are the other elements of the array `get_split_strings`?

Anyway, you can't concatenate an array and a string, so the operation `get_split_strings(0) & "pass %"` fails.

It's not quite clear to me what you're trying to do here. Do you want to concatenate the first element of the array to the string `"pass %"`? In that case you should change

```
get_split_strings(0) = Split(...)
```

to

```
get_split_strings = Split(...)
```

Or do you want to concatenate all elements of the array with the string `"pass %"`? Then you should `Join` the array before the concatenation:

```
... = Join(get_split_strings(0)) & "pass %"
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.Was out of office for some days. As you mentioned I wanted to append the string 'pass %' to another string content. (get_split_strings(0) contains a string). It worked for me in vba. But in vbs it doesn't. Though i made it up by using "wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, f2)" in place of get_split_strings(0). (See the question section). Accepting your answer as it contains clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The "Expected End of Statement- 800A0401" error is a **compilation** error. It's easily provoked by [messing quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16024894/603855). For example

```
wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, f2) = get_split_strings(0) & ""pass %"
```

won't compile. Your cited line, however, is syntactically correct.

Because line counting is error prone, publish a few more lines of your code.

Sorry to say, the longer code you published (Thanks!) is still syntactically correct. If the error line is reliably identified, the quotes are the first suspects. Depending on your editor, mixing 'normal' and fancy quotes may go undetected. Does your script compile, if you (temporarily) change

```
wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, f2) = get_split_strings(0) & "pass %"
```

to

```
wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, f2) = get_split_strings(0) '  & ""pass %" disabled!
```

**Update wrt comment:**

As the nasty line 'works' without the `& "pass %"` tail, re-type it with special care/attention to the quotes.

Comment: I have edited the question for your reference. Thanks.

Comment: Its really strange! When I re-typed it it shows 'Type Mismatch error 800A00D' in the same line but at a column position where nothing has been typed. i.e at line 111, column 18 where there is nothing. And no problems with the previous line(110) also.